# Excel/Powershell start a loop from row 2

Tags: excel, powershell, foreach

Actually I have this loop :

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\script2.csv) 
{ $firstname = $line.split(';')[0] 
 $lastname = $line.split(';')[1]
 $email = $line.split(';')[2]
 $newLine = "$firstname,""$lastname"",""$email"""
 $newLine >> newCSV.csv }
```

I use it to extract data and paste it in a correct format.

I would like to know what is the correct syntax to start it from the row 2 and not taking all my sheet ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why are you processing the CSV manually instead of using `Import-CSV`?

Comment: So basically, you want to remove the headers from a `;` delimited CSV file and write out a new `,` delimited csv with just the first data row ?

Comment: yes exactly !
I'm totaly new in scripting, this is the first one I wrote and I'm sur there is something better, but I try to learn how it works.

Comment: But.. Why would you want to remove the header row?

Comment: I don't really want to remove it. I just want to keep the header like it is from the Excel I extract data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select -Skip $N` to skip the first `$N` items of a collection:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\script2.csv |Select -Skip 1)
{
  $firstname = $line.split(';')[0] 
  $lastname = $line.split(';')[1]
  $email = $line.split(';')[2]
  $newLine = "$firstname,""$lastname"",""$email"""
  $newLine >> newCSV.csv
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to convert a CSV file that uses the semi-colon `;` as delimiter to a new Csv file that uses the comma `,` as delimiter, and in the process remove the header line from it, you can do:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\blah.csv' -Delimiter ';' | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
Out-String -Stream | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\newCSV.csv'
```