# CSV/Powershell Add an -Header

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, header

I have this loop :

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\script2.csv)
{ $firstname = $line.split(';')[0] 
$lastname = $line.split(';')[1]
$email = $line.split(';')[2] 
$newLine = """$firstname"",""$lastname"",""$email"""
$newLine >> newCSV.csv }
```

I would like to add a specific header but I don't know where I should write "-header" in my little script.

Thanks

Edit :

I have a file like that :

```
A;B;C 
A;B;C 
A;B;C 
A;B;C
```

And I need to have this :

```
"info1","info2","info3",...,"info18" 
"A","B",C","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"A","B",C","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"A","B",C","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"A","B",C","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Comment: `Import-Csv -Path .\script2.csv -Header 'FirstName','LastName','Email'`. You should not use `Get-Content` when dealing with CSV files as I tried to explain in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69723651/9898643). BTW. CSV is **not** Excel, but a structured set of data delimited by a certain character (usually the comma)

Comment: Yes I understand. I tried some syntax with Import-Csv but I don't know how to write my loop after that.
In my case I need a header like ("a","b","c","d"...) and after, all the data I extract from my loop and this is where I'm lost...

Comment: You don't need a loop at all. Import-Csv parses the data in the csv as **objects** and to write out these to a new csv file use Export-Csv. Didn't you read/try [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69725254/9898643) in the previous question?

Comment: I read it of course, so, maybe you can help me otherly.
I need to have all data from rows 2 and concatene them in only one column. This is why I tried with a loop but there is surely a easier way to do it.
My problem is, I have no idea about a correct syntax, I looked on internet since 2 weeks but it's hard alone when you are a beginner.

Comment: Please could you explain exactly what the desired output should be? Isn't `Import-Csv -Path .\script2.csv -Delimiter ';'  -Header 'FirstName','LastName','Email' | Export-Csv -Path '.\newCsv.csv' -NoTypeInformation` what you are after?

Comment: It's done, sorry

Comment: Is my answer indeed what you wanted? As you can see, no looping/splitting is needed if you use the right cmdlets for the job. If you feel my answer solved your problem, please mark it 'done' by clicking the large checkmark icon on the left. This helps others with a similar question finding it more easily.

Comment: Yeah it helps me.
I have edited my question a last time because I forgot to precise I need the exact syntax as I wrote.
This is where I'm stuck for so long time, I can't have more or less comma.
It's a specific file and if it is not like that it won't work

Comment: Please see the final edit to my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! This is all my fault, I thought every "" between comma were important but it's not. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have commented, this can simply be done without loop:

Your input CSV (script2.csv)

```
A;B;C 
A;B;C 
A;B;C 
A;B;C
```

```
# get objects from the input csv file and provide headers for the data
# then save this data with the default delimiter comma to a new file
Import-Csv -Path '.\script2.csv' -Delimiter ';'  -Header 'info1','info2','info3','info4','info5' | 
Export-Csv -Path '.\newCsv.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

will give you a new file 'newCsv.csv' looking like this:

```
"info1","info2","info3","info4","info5"
"A","B","C",,
"A","B","C",,
"A","B","C",,
"A","B","C",,
```

---

If you need more fields as you have commented, you can simply create a string array to hod all the wanted headers and use that.

Something like

```
$header = 1..18 | ForEach-Object {"info$_"}
Import-Csv -Path '.\script2.csv' -Delimiter ';' -Header $header | 
Export-Csv -Path '.\newCsv.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

This will save the newCsv.csv with this content:

```
"info1","info2","info3","info4","info5","info6","info7","info8","info9","info10","info11","info12","info13","info14","info15","info16","info17","info18"
"A","B","C",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
"A","B","C",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
"A","B","C",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
"A","B","C",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

*ANY* software reading such a file should be able to handle the empty fields, as there is absolutely no reason to fill these with `""` to denote the field is empty.. Reading/Importing CSV should always return values as **strings** anyway, as Import-Csv does.

---

- [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) Creates table-like custom objects from the items in a delimiter-separated value file. Usually this delimiter is the comma, hence the extension *Comma Separated Values* (.csv)
- [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) Converts objects into a series of delimiter-separated value (CSV) strings and saves the strings to a file.
- [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) Gets the content of a text file and returns a string array where the lines are split on the NewLine character(s).
  When adding switch `-Raw` to this cmdlet, it returns the content of the file as single multiline string including NewLine characters.

Comment: I finished my script, and, when I tried to import it in my printer, it doesn't works...
I tried manually and finally I need every "" between comma.
Do you have an idea how I can do that ?

Comment: @MaximeL That's WEIRD... Anyway, you could try after saving the csv file `(Get-Content -Path '.\newCsv.csv' -Raw) -replace ',,', ',"",' -replace '(?ms),$', ',""' | Set-Content -Path '.\newCsv.csv'`